# How to Load Different Home Page according to screen size

Tags: html, css, httpwebresponse, adaptive-design

I want to load different home page according screen size. Can anyone help about it ?

For Example,
for screen-size < 960 px I want to display default landing page as index1.html
and
for screen-size > 960 px I want to display default landing page as index2.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As suggested, I would do this with a script based upon a media query. I recommend [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs) as a lightweight solution if you plan on making many queries or changing assets based upon queries. That said, while I don't know what problem you're attempting to solve, I believe the method of solution goes against the principles of the responsive web. What happens when a user goes from one media query to another and back? How are you handling pages redirecting? Consider using blocks that can be repurposed as the medium your audience changes. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've tagged this question `responsive-design`, but you are asking about how to do "adaptive design." Responsive design would be having a single HTML page that adjusts to the medium it is being viewed in, for example by using media queries. I won't get into a debate about which is better, but I add this in case you're interested in responsive design so that you have some ideas to google.

A way to do what you are asking is to have a bit of JavaScript on your page that checks the width of the window and redirects if necessary:

```
// In index2.html
if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
    window.location = "index1.html";
}

// In index1.html
if (window.innerWidth >= 960) {
    window.location = "index2.html";
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir. It seems to work . Only problem is when I resize the browser, I have to reload the Page (Ctrl + F5) . I tried window.resize() function. but it didn't work.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize - There is a window.onresize event that you can define.

Comment: You might want to consider, though, how annoying it might be for a user if your site reloads every time they adjust the screen size.

Comment: This is not a good way to do this. You should use responsive design instead as it will save huge headaches later, when you're maintaining a mobile and desktop site.

Comment: So far responsive design has been a huge headache. I like the idea of "show me these pages for mobile", "show me different pages for desktop". Especially for advertising, showing the mobile user an advert for desktop software when the don't own a desktop computer would irritate them.

Comment: Be careful with this, it’s bad practice. It’s loaded with wrong assumptions and easily leads  to even more. Viewport size does not at all indicate that users are on a tablet or phone, they could just have opened their browser window in split-mode, not maximised or in a zoomed view. 
@AmericanUmlaut should we maybe add a warning to this answer, as this practice really is harmful?

Comment: @Andy The warning would need to go on the question; this answer is a pretty good way to do what OP specifically requested, and I'm clear in the response that this isn't how you do responsive design. Additionally, there's already discussion in the comments to this answer as well as the comment on the question making clear this isn't best practice. I think things are okay here.

Answer (score 8):

I know this was asked and answered a while ago, but I think the solution I'm adding is better than the accepted answer as it involves no reloading *and* works on resizing.  Define two CSS classes, .HideOnMobile and .ShowOnMobile and use them in two top level DIV elements.

Then use media queries to set the display value of those two classes to none or initial, to display or hide each DIV according to the screen width.

Update: the author of the accepted answer has kindly commented below that they believe this answer is best at solving the problem behind the question.

```css
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .HideOnMobile {
    display: none;
  }
  .ShowOnMobile {
    display: initial;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .HideOnMobile {
    display: initial;
  }
  .ShowOnMobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ShowOnMobile">
  MOBILE content
</div>
<div class="HideOnMobile">
  DESKTOP content
</div>
```

Comment: I think you missed this part: for screen-size < 960 px I want to display default landing page as index1.html and for screen-size > 960 px I want to display default landing page as index2.html

Comment: Well, first obviously change the max-width and min-width values in my solution accordingly.  And yes, my solution does not allow or require the 2 different index.html files, but it does display completely different content according to screen width, *Without a reload*, which I think is far better.  It also works on resizing!

Comment: @WendiT As I preface by saying I am suggesting a different approach, I think the downvote is not helpful.

Comment: Upvoted because, although my accepted answer is the best way to solve the literal question posted, this answer describes the best way to actually solve the problem behind the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution. It worked but the page was reloading continuously. By this approach solved the reload problem and I've added a function that can help reload the page automatically when viewport size change.

```
// refreshing page automatically when viewport size change  
window.onresize = function(event) {
  document.location.reload(true);
}

var href = window.location.href.split("/")
var html_location = href[href.length-1]

if (window.innerWidth >= 960 && html_location !== "index.html") {
    window.location = "index.html";
}

if (window.innerWidth < 960 && html_location !== "index2.html") {
    window.location = "index2.html";
}
```