# How to load html files on different devices using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML documents, one for device width ***less than 768px*** and another for device ***greater than 768px***. How do I load each document using the device detection method?

Comment: This is exactly what you are looking for:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899097/how-to-load-different-home-page-according-to-screen-size consider researching your question  before asking it on SO

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Load Different Home Page according to screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899097/how-to-load-different-home-page-according-to-screen-size)

Comment: What are the steps to follow while doing device detectable sites by having separate mobile and desktop files.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your page:

```
<script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width < 768) {
        window.open("./smaller.html", "_self");
    } else {
        window.open("./greather.html", "_self");
    }
</script>
```