# How do I run one script for computer screen and another for mobile (HTML CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am building a single-page website for an application for a coding Boot-camp.

I have 2 HTML files and 2 CSS files as the content of the page is different depending on which device is being used (either mobile or laptop).

The four files are:
"index.html" and "styles.css"
and
"mobile.html" and "mobile.css"

My aim is to have it so if the screen width is > 700px then it will run:
"index.html" and "styles.css"

and if device size is < 700px it will run:
"mobile.html" and "mobile.css"

I had added

```
@media only screen and (max-width 700px)
```

into the mobile.css file, but this just stopped all the CSS working.

How would I get the page to run the correct scripts at the correct time?

Comment: This should help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899097/how-to-load-different-home-page-according-to-screen-size

Comment: Could you precise what “all CSS stops working” means?
And delivering different HTML to different screen sizes is considered a bad practice. why would you like to do that?
See also [Browser detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)

Comment: @andy When I put in the media line in all CSS no longer loaded, I wasn't sure if the issue was caused as a result of only viewing the item in the 'inspect' mobile view on the desktop. Or if the error was a result me not telling the site which program to run correctly.  I am still trying to make the site responsive, but I am just worried that I might miss the deadline (I'm learning HTML as I go). so I thought if I had a working model, then I could improve it with my remaining time.

Comment: To do that you need advanced load balancing stuff to determine if the traffic is mobile and redirect to the right "file". There is no point of doing things like this and not to be rude but unless you are a savy network guy the way to go is responsive design. Just to add no matter what responsive design is pretty much the way to go in any situation

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a small misunderstanding. You don't need two html files. What you do is you modify your ids and classes in your index.html to make it fit on mobile devices. The two CSS files are a good first step though.

Insert your CSS files like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css">
```

Make sure you insert your mobile.css **after** your styles.css so you want all your styles from styles.css but at some breakpoints modify some ids or classes with your mobile.css.

So to express it in natural language: Hey styles.css. I want you to style all my ids and classes but if mobile.css reaches a breakpoint, where it wants to modify eg. #menu-bar to have a green background, I use the modified styles in mobile.css instead.

Example:

`styles.css`

```css
#menu-bar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

`mobile.css`

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #menu-bar {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Notice how I didn't declare the width again? This is because everything that was declared already in styles.css will stay the same. Just the values you alter in your mobile.css media query breakpoints will change.

Make sure to research media queries to get a better unserstanding of it eg. [from this article](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/what-are-css-and-media-query-breakpoints#:%7E:text=Essentially%2C%20media%20query%20breakpoints%20are,offers%20an%20optimal%20user%20experience.)

Comment: For performance reasons, you should include the media query in the [`media` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-media). Otherwise both CSS will download, even if not used.

Comment: @Andy well that won't work for the specific css in the answer as you would have to duplicate all css again, instead of just the differences. Like `width: 100%;` would have to be declared again. I mean everybody can do as they please but it makes no sense imo.

Comment: If giving advice on responsive please do it properly, Mobile first so styles.css should contain the styles so FROM mobile, the other could be large-screen.css and use `min-width`. In my opinion just keep it in the same file.

Comment: I had tried this approach as my first attempt, but to get it looking correct I had to change the HTML file as well, (now this is likely down to my skill level). I do intend on spending more time rewriting the script so I can have it in only one HTML file. However I don't want to miss my deadline, so was hoping there was a way to tell each screen size which piece of code to run. I have followed the page that Sanjay suggested in the comments above but it doesn't seem to be running as planned